# Partial fractions for inverse laplace transform

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform

I have the following function for which I need to find the inverse laplace transform:

$$\frac1{s(s^2+1)^2}$$

Am I correct in saying the partial fraction is:

$$\frac1{s(s^2+1)^2}=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{Bs+C}{s^2+1}+\frac{Ds+E}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct, next, you need to determine the coefficients.

Comment: Yep, I ended up getting $F(s)=\frac1s+\frac{-s}{s^2+1}+\frac{-s}{(s^2+1)^2}$


So, $f(t)=1-cos(t)-\frac{t}{2}sin(t)$ I think?

I read somewhere that for the last term$\frac{-s}{(s^2+1)^2}$, $\frac{-t}{2}sin(t)$ is the inverse laplace transform... is that correct? Do you have time to maybe point me in the right direction so I can figure out how to get the inverse laplace transform for the last term? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to evaluate the ILT when there are just poles (i.e., no branch points like roots and logarithms) is to apply the residue theorem.  In this case, the ILT is simply the sum of the residues at the poles of the LT.  That is,

$$\begin{align}f(t) &= \operatorname*{Res}_{s=0} \frac{e^{s t}}{s(1+s^2)^2}+ \operatorname*{Res}_{s=i} \frac{e^{s t}}{s(1+s^2)^2}+\operatorname*{Res}_{s=-i} \frac{e^{s t}}{s(1+s^2)^2}\\ &= \frac{e^{(0) t}}{(0^2+1)^2}+\left[\frac{d}{ds}\frac{e^{s t}}{s(s+i)^2}\right]_{s=i} +\left[\frac{d}{ds}\frac{e^{s t}}{s(s-i)^2}\right]_{s=-i}\\ &= 1+\left[ \frac{e^{s t} ((s+i) s t-3 s-i)}{s^2 (s+i)^3}\right]_{s=i}+\left [\frac{e^{s t} ((s-i) s t-3 s+i)}{s^2 (s-i)^3} \right ]_{s=-i}\\ &=1+\left[-\frac{1}{8} i e^{i t} (-2 t-4 i)\right]+\left[\frac{1}{8} i e^{-i t} (-2 t+4 i)\right]\\&=1-\cos{t}-\frac12 t \sin{t}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. The coefficients are...SPOILER ALERT...

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

$$A=1,$$
$$B=-1,$$
$$C=E=0,$$
$$D=-1.$$

Comment: Awesome I got the same thing. As I said above though, I ended up getting $F(s)=\frac1s+\frac{-s}{s^2+1}+\frac{-s}{(s^2+1)^2}$


So, $f(t)=1-cos(t)-\frac{t}{2}sin(t)$ I think? BUT

For the last term, I didn't actually figure it out myself.. Any ideas how I can go about getting there? Can't seem to get it.. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome! Please feel free to upvote+flag the answer if you found it useful. Regarding $\frac{s}{(s^2+1)^2}$: consider the Laplace transform $\mathcal L(f)(s)$ of $f(t)=\sin t$; derive it w.r.t. to $s$...what do you get?